# Chromium/Chromedriver suddenly stopped displaying special chars properly using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping https://fbref.com/en/squads/12192a4c/Greuther-Furth-Stats with Beautiful Soup and Selenium which worked fine until suddenly some special chars are not displayed properly anymore. Here's a screenshot how it's displayed now:

[image]

I am using:

- Chromium (Version 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) for Linux Mint (64-bit))
- Chromedriver for Chrome 96 from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Any idea how to solve it? I already cleared cache in Chromium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see on the web site and can be seen on your screenshot, the problem is not with your code, it's a bug on the targeted web page you are trying to scrape.
Selenium and Beautiful Soup can read the actual texts displayed on the targeted web pages, whey are not intended to fix Front End bugs of the targeted web pages.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this might had something to do with Chrome/Browser settings. It's kind of weird because it started happening out of nowhere and the behaviour is not consistent throughout the website (e. g. here it is displayed correctly https://fbref.com/en/squads/bc357bf7/Koln-Stats)

Comment: In case this is the site of company where you are working you can ask you R&D programmers to fix this bug on production. But I guess you doing some learning project. In this case you can wait until the bug will be fixed or select another site to work on.

Comment: I doublechecked on a Mac and I do not encounter this behaviour...

Comment: I opened it again now on my Windows PC and see it's OK now to.. Looks like they fixed the bug :)

Comment: https://fbref.com/en/squads/247c4b67/2018-2019/Arminia-Stats here as well? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, now I see the broken signs again... weird. But again, we can do nothing about it.

Comment: They have problems with encoding non-ASCII letters

Comment: This page displays perfectly on Mac/Safari but not on Chromium/Linux and ?/Windows. This sucks. I'll wait a day or two and accept your answer, as soon as it works again.

Comment: No problem. Anyway it's a bug on their side.